# Cannot select form with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have inherited a project, that provides an order form to a customer.

The order form is a table, and the adding to cart is (meant to be!) handled with jQuery.

Code I have to work with looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <form id="prod1" method="post" action="">
        <tr>
            <td>Prod Name</td><td><input type="text" name="prod1qty" id="prod1qty" /></td><td><input type="button" id="prod1add" /></td>
        <tr>
    </form>
    <form id="prod2" method="post" action="">
        <tr>
            <td>Prod Name</td><td><input type="text" name="prod2qty" id="prod2qty" /></td><td><input type="button" id="prod2add" /></td>
        <tr>
    </form>
    <form id="prod3" method="post" action="">
        <tr>
            <td>Prod Name</td><td><input type="text" name="prod3qty" id="prod3qty" /></td><td><input type="button" id="prod3add" /></td>
        <tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

I am trying to select all the input type="button" elements within forms with id's starting "prod" with jQuery so I can give them a click function...

```
$("form[id^='prod'] :input[type='button']").click(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

But its failing...I tried to see if it was reaching the element by replacing .click() with .css('border', '1px solid red') but it wasn't picking it up.

I then noticed in firebug that the `<form>` was greyed-out, and closed on the same line, ie:

```
<form id="prod1" method="post" action="" />
<tr>
    <td>Prod Name</td><td><input type="text" name="prod1qty" id="prod1qty" /></td><td><input type="button" id="prod1add" /></td>
<tr>
<form id="prod2" method="post" action="" />
<tr>
    <td>Prod Name</td><td><input type="text" name="prod2qty" id="prod2qty" /></td><td><input type="button" id="prod2add" /></td>
<tr>
```

It seems that the code is valid HTML (put it through the validator), so why is this happening?

Thanks!
Josh

Comment: You are wrong. It isn't valid HTML. Form elements may not be child elements for tables or parent elements of table rows.

Comment: Ah, ok. Just got rid of the forms, gave the `tr` the id the `form` used to have, changed `form` to `tr` in the selector and its working. Thanks!

I'm guessing the validator only checks for valid syntax and not structure validity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd better close this question properly...

The comment by [David Dorward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/david-dorward) answered my question.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question. Perhaps if you use '`class=prod`' and check `$('.prod').click(function (){});` might get you the access to the elements inside your clicked form.